# RTCPeerConnection not sending stream

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am trying to establish an RTCPeerConnection and using pusher for handshaking through the following code

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
        "iceServers": [
            {url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
            {url: 'stun:stunserver.org'},
        ]
    }
);

pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (!event.candidate) return;
    console.log("icecandidate: ", event);
    presenceChannel.trigger("client-ice", {data: event.candidate});
};

pc.onaddstream = event => {
    console.warn("stream added");
    vidEl.srcObject = event.stream;
};

//for when pusher channel subscription is successful from the other end
presenceChannel.bind("client-subscribed", () => {
    console.warn(pc);
    pc.createOffer().then(offer => {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), () => {
            console.warn("offer created: ", offer);
            presenceChannel.trigger("client-offer", {data: offer});
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.warn("error on offer: ", error);
    });
});

presenceChannel.bind("client-answer", function (data) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.data), () => {
        console.warn("received an answer");
        pc.addStream(currentStream);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.warn(pc);
        }, 5000);
    }, error => {
        console.warn("error in answer: ", error)
    });
});

presenceChannel.bind("client-ice", function (data) {
    pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.data)).catch(error => {
        console.warn("ice error: ", error);
    });
});

//and the remote peer

presenceChannel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", () => {
    if (currentStream === undefined) {
        presenceChannel.trigger("client-recipient-error");
        pusher.unsubscribe(channel);

        return false;
    }

    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
            "iceServers": [
                {url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
                {url: 'stun:stunserver.org'},
            ]
        }
    );

    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
        if (!event.candidate) return;
        console.log("icecandidate: ", event);
        presenceChannel.trigger("client-ice", {data: event.candidate});
    };

    pc.onaddstream = event => {
        console.warn("stream added");
        vidEl.srcObject = event.stream;
    };

    presenceChannel.trigger("client-subscribed", {});
    console.warn(pc);
    presenceChannel.bind("client-ice", function (data) {
        pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.data)).catch(error => {
            console.warn("ice error: ", error);
        });
    });

    presenceChannel.bind("client-offer", signalData => {
        // console.warn("client-signal", signalData);
        console.warn("received an offer");

        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signalData.data), () => {
            return pc.createAnswer().then(answer => {
                pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer), () => {
                    presenceChannel.trigger("client-answer", {data: answer});
                    console.warn("created answer");
                    pc.addStream(currentStream);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.warn(pc);
                    }, 7000);
                });
            }).then(() => {

            }).catch(error => {
                console.warn("error on answer: ", error);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Am not getting any errors the `rtcpeerconnection` variable on both ends have both local and remote description so am assuming the connection was well established right? Or this doesn't mean the connection was established, (i need help on this too to know if the connection is established or not and how to know), however everything runs, all the events and functions execute (except the `onicecandidate` event which i know its just not being triggered am not worried about this though) except for `onaddstream` event, so am guessing if this is not being triggered and  am adding a stream then is the connection really on, wasted alot of time on this and frankly its just driving me nuts, any help **AND I MEAN ANY HELP** would be highly appreciated cause it's my first time handling `RTCPeerConnection` and maybe there is something am doing wrong or taking a wrong approach, please point this out too if its the case and show me the right way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Am using chrome and it does not yet support addTrack, gave me an error earlier that addTrack is not a function so fell back to addStream.